# retweets not always included in user timeline

Tags: r, twitter, package

I'm using R twitteR packages to extract specific users tweets via "userTimeline":

```
require(twitteR)
timeline <- userTimeline('screenname', n=200)
```

My problem is that for some users retweets are included, and for others they are not
included, and I can't understand why.

Can you help me?

Thank you,
Stefania

Comment: probably not but could some of the retweets by protected and hence not available?

Comment: I don't think they are protected, it also happen with my retweets.